# Can I sue the car dealership for fraud if they let my ex finance a car under my name?

Tags: car, fraud, auto-loan, law, lawsuit-settlement

About 4 years ago (2018), i was living with my ex and I leased a car for 3 years but under my name only. 2 years later (2020), we broke up but i let her use the car for the last year of the lease. When the end of the lease came up (2021), she wanted to keep the car so I told her if she wants to keep it she has to change it over to her name and take me off. And if I needed to be there then I would come. She went to the dealership by herself because she said she knew people there and few days later she tells me that she leased the car again and that my name will be off of the title soon. Few months later, I find out that she actually financed the car for 6 years under my name only. (I did not sign a single piece of paper and if there is a signature then someone forged it.) I thought I was screwed because she already started making payments so I told her to make sure to make payments. But now she got the car repo-ed, she totaled the car with no insurance and my credit has dropped from 710 to 618. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: https://law.stackexchange.com/ may be a better venue for your "can I sue" question. You should post your general location (country and state/province).

Comment: You should have gotten a lawyer immediately after she re-leased the car in your name. You should absolutely get a lawyer *now*. (I would be concerned that your failure to do anything initially could be construed as acceptance of the lease, but IANAL.)